# Erro cors no laravel quando uso middleware jwt.auth

Tags: laravel, cors, jwt

Quando eu tento fazer uma requisição http dentro do meu middleware jwt.auth eu recebo:

> :9000/#/dash/tipodeprodutos:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'https://api2.jcontrole.com.br/api/notificacoes/gerais' from origin
>   'http://localhost:9000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request
>   header field token is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in
>   preflight response.

| Framework | Laravel 
| Framework version | 5.6 
| Package version | Usando "barryvdh/laravel-cors": "^0.9.2", e "tymon/jwt-auth": "^0.5.12"
| PHP version | PHP 5.6.36 (cli) (built: Apr 25 2018 16:45:32)

Eu tenho essas rotas sem o jwt middleware:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Auth::routes();

//Route::post('login', 'UserController@acessarSistema'); 
Route::post('login', 'UserController@authenticate');
```

Elas funcionam normalmente mas quando eu tento fazer uma requisição em um grupo que possui o jwt.auth middleware eu recebo erro de cors:

```
$this->group(['middleware' => 'jwt.auth', ['prefix' => 'api']], function() {

      Route::post('admin/tipo-produto', 'TipoProdutosController@create')->name('cadastrar_tipo_produto')->middleware('checarPermissaoTela');

})
```

Eu tentei usar o pacote de cors, adicionei ele no meu middlewareGroups:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
        **\Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class,**
    ],
];
```

Minha cors config em config/cors.php:

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Laravel CORS
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | allowedOrigins, allowedHeaders and allowedMethods can be set to array('*')
    | to accept any value.
    |
    */

    'supportsCredentials' => false,
    'allowedOrigins' => ['*'],
    'allowedOriginsPatterns' => [],
    'allowedHeaders' => ['*'],
    'allowedMethods' => ['*'],
    'exposedHeaders' => [],
    'maxAge' => 0,

];
```

Também tentei adicionar no public/index.php:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');  
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
```

Comment: Tive o mesmo problema mas utilizando Angular. Buscando no google encontrei esse post https://daveceddia.com/access-control-allow-origin-cors-errors-in-angular/ que é bem completo e dá várias opções de solução. Resolvi o meu com a primeira sugestão, alterando o servidor da minha API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Foi resolvido no servidor Apache alterando o arquivo apache.conf:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```